# first argument to append must be slice (struct and golang)

Tags: go

hello i am a begginer in golang and i am working on a shopping cart app, every time i try to excute the code it shows  "first argument to append must be slice" here is the code
package cart

```
type Cart struct {
    items map[string]Item
}

type Item struct {
    id       string
    name     string
    price    float32
    quantity int
}

func NewItem(i string, n string, p float32) Item {
    return Item{
        id:       i,
        name:     n,
        price:    p,
        quantity: 0,
    }
}

func NewCart() Cart {
    return Cart{
        items: map[string]Item{}}
}

func (box *Cart) AddItem(item Item) []Item {
    box.items = append(box.items, item)
    return box.items
}

func main() {
    utils.CreateLogger("shopping-cart")
    shoppingCart := cart.NewCart()

    item1 := cart.NewItem("potato121", "Potato", 10)

    err := shoppingCart.AddItem(item1)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you tried to add an object into a `map` using `append()`, on this line of code:

```
box.items = append(box.items, item)
```

Meanwhile the `box.items` type is a `map[string]Item`.

```
type Cart struct {
    items map[string]Item
}
```

The `append()` built in function [can only be used on a slice data type](https://godoc.org/builtin#append).

---

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, whether to use a map or a slice as the type of `.items`. But if you want the `.items` property to be a slice, then change your code into this:

```
type Cart struct {
    items []Item
}

func NewCart() Cart {
    return Cart{
        items: make([]Item, 0)}
}
```

If you want the `.items` property to be a `map`, change your code into this:

```
func NewCart() Cart {
    return Cart{
        items: map[string]Item{}}
}

func (box *Cart) AddItem(item Item) map[string]Item {
    box.items[item.id] = item
    return box.items
}
```